# What's better to scrape a website : selenium or request?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have an URL to **scrape** and i ask me what's the best method.

With selenium for example:

```
executable_path = "....\\chromedriver" browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
url = "xxxxxxxxxx" browser.get(url) timeout = 20
# find_elements_by_xpath returns an array of selenium objects.
titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('[data-test-id="xxxx"]'
```

This method launches Chrome Browser. On windows i have to install both "Chrome browser" and a Chrome Driver in the same version. But what happens in a Linux server: no problem to install Chrome driver but it's not a problem to install a Chrome browser on a server without graphic interface?

Do you suggest me to use rather request module than selenium because my URL is already built.
The risk to be caught by website is more important with selenium or request?

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one URL to scrape Selenium is better because it's easier to code than requests.

For exemple : if you need to scroll down to make your data appear, it will be harder to do without a browser

If you want to do intensive scraping maybe you should try requests with beautifulsoup, it will use way less ressource on your server.

You can also use scrapy, it's very easy to spoof the user agent with it, this makes your bot harder to detect.

If you scrape responsibly with a delay between 2 requests, you should not be detected with either method. You can check the robot.txt document to be safe

Comment: Thanks a lot Cyriaque Pin!